# c# WebBrowser Contrl load custom MIME

Tags: c#, webforms, mime

I made a winform to load a page.
In the page there is only a webbrowser control.
There is a html tag like

```
<object type='application/x-eloamplugin' ></object>
```

It worked on IE 11,and 7,8,9,10, but It doesn't work on my winform.

The webform show this test page:
[webbrowser version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbJgI.png)

I have installed the "dll" which register "application/x-eloamplugin" correctly, because it worked on IE.

I think the WebBrowser Control don't know what is "application/x-eloamplugin".

What can I do to make it worked on WinForm(WebBrowser Contrl to display it).

Thank you for helping me.

Environment: Window 7, .Net Framework 2.0 (any version is Ok)